# Conjunto de Condições WHERE , AND e OR no SQL não produz o resultado esperado

Tags: mysql, sql, where

Estou tentando buscar alguns registros com uma sintaxe bem simples, mas não está funcionando. Estou fazendo alguma coisa errada e não estou percebendo. Alguém pode dar uma mão?

Preciso buscar todos os registros de 2017 exceto FRETES e IMPOSTOS! 
Tenho isso:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_01 
WHERE data_reg LIKE '2017%' 
  AND (Desc <> 'FRETE' OR Desc <> 'IMPOSTO');
```

Mas dessa forma está vindo todos os registros de 2017, inclusive fretes e impostos.

Comment: qual o nome do campo, "Desc?"

Comment: @HenriqueSantiago DescPart

Answer (score 7):

Utilize assim:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_01
WHERE data_reg LIKE '2017%'
AND Desc <> 'FRETE'
AND Desc <> 'IMPOSTO';
```

O motivo de dar errado no seu código é porque usava o OR. Se fosse `FRETE`, temos que `FRETE` é diferente de `IMPOSTO`, então daria verdadeiro. Se fosse `IMPOSTO`, temos que `IMPOSTO` é diferente de `FRETE`, então também daria verdadeiro.

Ao usar o AND, nós temos que o registro deve ser diferente de `FRETE` **e também** diferente de `IMPOSTO`.

Comment: Maravilha Victor, funcionou ! 
muito simples !

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar `not in` também, exemplo: `and Desc not in ('FRETE','IMPOSTO');`